# xCode, table view cells in distance order

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5

In my app I am trying to make a table view order it self within distance order from the device! So lets say I have 20 rows in the table, they then go into distance order.

The only problem is, I am quite new to making apps so may need quite a detailed explanation! I have been trying to do this now for ages...

If someone assist what code and what I need to do in Xcode please do! Will be highly appreciated!!

any help?

Comment: distance from your mobile device

Comment: what data is being shown in your tableView? try to be more specific and also any code that you tried could help people help you!

Comment: It the table it will basically be the names of each club... I also have the longitudes and latitudes of each venue... so want the tableview to go into distance order of each club when a user opens it  :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading up CLLocation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) as it will provide you all the info you'll need to figure out the user's current location.  Then once you have the current location, you can use that and the lat/long on each location to figure out the distances.  Once you set your distances on your objects, you can sort them by the property on your object (a club, in your case).

I'm using the following snippet to calculate distance from the user's current location to another location (a facility, in this case):

```
Facility *facility = [_facilities objectAtIndex:i];
CLLocation *facilityLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[facility.latitude floatValue] longitude:[facility.longitude floatValue]];
if(facilityLocation){
    CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:facilityLocation];
    double mileConversion = distance * 0.000621371192;

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
    facility.distanceFromCurrentLocation = [formatter numberFromString:[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:mileConversion]]];
}
```

I got the mile conversion from somewhere on SO a while back, and it's because there are 1,609.344 meters in a mile.  If you only need meters, you can exclude that conversion.  Also note, I'm using only 1 decimal for UI display purposes.